# Read file and strip \n and split for list

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, strip

I have an assignment in which I have to read a file "words.csv":

```
Hemuli,Muumipappa,13,4
Abbath,Fenriz,6,6
```

And I should print it out as following:

```
Hemuli 13 - 4 Muumipappa
Abbath 6 - 6 Fenriz
```

My code so far:

```
def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words) as tulos:
        tulokset = tulos.read()
        a = tulokset.split(",")
        print(a)
```

This gives me a following **`list`**:

```
['Hemuli', 'Muumipappa', '13', '4\nAbbath', 'Fenriz', '6', '6']
```

Which is exactly what I want, but how do I proceed to strip down that **\n**? The "4" and "Abbath" should be in one of their own indexes. Can't seem to figure it out... After that I could use indexes and print out with format().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `splitlines()` while reading

```
def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words) as tulos:
        return tulos.read().splitlines()

# output: ['Hemuli,Muumipappa,13,4', 'Abbath,Fenriz,6,6']
```

Then split the string `.split(',')`

```
for i in nayta_tulokset(words):
    _f = i.split(",")
    print("{} {} - {} {}".format(_f[0], _f[-2], _f[-1], _f[1]))

# Hemuli 13 - 4 Muumipappa
# Abbath 6 - 6 Fenriz
```

Comment: Thank very much for taking your time and explaining this to me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the output you want, you need to read each line separately and print it out as expected.

Building up, on your code, here how you can proceed

```
def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words) as tulos:
        for line in tulos.read().split('\n'):
           a = line.split(",")
           print("{} {} - {} {}".format(a[0], a[2], a[3], a[1]))
```

instead of using `tulos.read().split('\n')`, you can use `tulos.readlines()`, which will take care of reading you file into a list of lines. So after refactoring, the code will look like this:

```
def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words) as tulos:
        for line in tulos.readlines():
           a = line.split(",")
           print("{} {} - {} {}".format(a[0], a[2], a[3], a[1]))
```

**More Details:** 
I guess the only somewhat ambiguous part of the code is the following:

```
"{} {} - {} {}".format(a[0], a[2], a[3], a[1])
```

Which is equivalent to the following string concatenation:

```
 a[0] +" " + a[2] +" - " + a[3] + " " +a[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that makes use of [list comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php) and the string format as above could be:

```
def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words, 'r') as f:
        return list(map(lambda x:"{} {} - {} {}".format(x[0],x[2],x[3],x[1]), map(lambda x:x.split(','),f.read().split())))
```

so

```
nayta_tulokset('words.csv')
['Hemuli 13 - 4 Muumipappa', 'Abbath 6 - 6 Fenriz']
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use regular expressions. Like so:

```
import re

def nayta_tulokset(words):
    with open(words) as tulos:
        tulokset = tulos.read()
        #a = re.findall(r"[\w']+", tulokset)
        a = re.split(",\n", tulokset)
```

This should give you:

```
['Hemuli', 'Muumipappa', '13', '4', 'Abbath', 'Fenriz', '6', '6']
```

Comment: Or just use the split function. `a=re.split(",\n", tulokset)`